# Data.table left join and aggregate/concatenate/group_concat

Tags: r, data.table

I have tables like:

```
x = data.table(Id=c(1,1,2,3,3,4), Name=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), TxId=c(10, 11, 20, 30, 31, 40))
#Id Name TxId
#1:  1    A   10
#2:  1    A   11
#3:  2    B   20
#4:  3    C   30
#5:  3    C   31
#6:  4    D   40

y = data.table(Name=c("A", "B", "B", "C"), Family=c("A-alpha", "B-beta", "B-gamma", "C-delta"))
#   Name  Family
#1:    A A-alpha
#2:    B  B-beta
#3:    B B-gamma
#4:    C C-delta
```

I can do the left-join and concatenation, but I only want one output row for each row in X.

```
# Left join X to Y on Name column
xy = y[x, on="Name"]
#   Name  Family Id TxId
#1:    A A-alpha  1   10
#2:    A A-alpha  1   11
#3:    B  B-beta  2   20
#4:    B B-gamma  2   20
#5:    C C-delta  3   30
#6:    C C-delta  3   31
#7:    D      NA  4   40

# Concatenate Family column
xy[, Family:=paste0(Family, collapse=", "), by=c("Name", "TxId")]
#   Name          Family Id TxId
#1:    A         A-alpha  1   10
#2:    A         A-alpha  1   11
#3:    B B-beta, B-gamma  2   20
#4:    B B-beta, B-gamma  2   20
#5:    C         C-delta  3   30
#6:    C         C-delta  3   31
#7:    D              NA  4   40
```

**How do I get rid of the extra row for B?** I want it to be unique on Id/TxId. i.e.

```
#   Name          Family Id TxId
#1:    A         A-alpha  1   10
#2:    A         A-alpha  1   11
#3:    B B-beta, B-gamma  2   20
#5:    C         C-delta  3   30
#6:    C         C-delta  3   31
#7:    D              NA  4   40
```

If I do as eddi comments:

```
xy[, .(Family=paste0(Family, collapse=", "), by=c("Name", "TxId")])
```

I get the correct result. But if I try to add other columns, it doesn't work (I get the same result as if I had done the `:=` version):

```
xy[, .(Id, Family=paste0(Family, collapse=", ")), by=c("Name", "TxId")]
```

Comment: don't create a new column, instead do `xy[, .(Family = paste0(...)), by = ...]`

Comment: Have you tried `xy[, .(Family = paste0(Family, collapse = ", "), by = c("Id", "Name", "TxId")]`?

Comment: @UweBlock, no I hadn't tried that. It's counter-intuitive, but it works! Another thing I found that works is unique() but your approach is about 30% faster. Post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try

```
xy[, .(Family = paste0(Family, collapse = ", "), by = c("Id", "Name", "TxId")]
```

I'll *try* to explain:
If `Id` is part of the group-by it will only appear once for each unique value of `Id` (to be exact, for each unique combination of `Id`, `Name`, `TxId`). If `Id` is included in the `j`-expression, i.e., `.(Id, Family = paste0(Family, collapse = ", ")` then every row of `Id` will be included in the result set despite `Family` is being aggregated.